# Access iCloud on my Mac without my phone?

Tags: macos, icloud, two-factor-authentication

I left my phone at home, I'm on my Mac. I go to icloud.com. It tells me to enter the code sent to my devices. Normally a code pops up on my Mac but it's not this time.

How do I access icloud on my mac without my phone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System preferences → iCloud → account details → security → get a verification code:  for Mojave

System Preferences → Apple ID → Password & Security → Get a verification code: for Catalina

Comment: You must be on a different version of MacOS than me. [There is no "iCloud" in system preferences](https://imgur.com/hybvacs) MacOS 10.15.3

Comment: Found it. System Preferences -> Apple ID -> Password & Security -> Get a verification code